# Difficulty dual booting with Windows XP

Tags: dual-boot

I have just downloaded Ubuntu onto usb stick. When rebooting computer I get to where there is option of using Windows or Ubuntu, but cannot highlight Ubuntu. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your UP/DOWN keys to select/highlight Ubuntu, don't use the mouse arrow/cursor. Besides, check the connection of your keyboard (is it a USB keyboard? if it's so, try plugging it in a different USB port. It's happened to me that a USB Keyboard gave problems at boot because it wasn't being recognized by the system).

Comment: I found that by plugging keyboard into a different usb port I could download successfully -now I need to partition the drive.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you cannot highlight Ubuntu. If you have installed it correctly then usually the Ubuntu is in the first position and Windows in the last. You can use Up and Down arrow to navigate to Windows. If you do not select anything, in 9 seconds Ubuntu will automatically boot.